# Start-Process * -Passthru does not return the correct PID

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64

```
$app = Start-Process notepad -Passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
```

This method returns the wrong PID. I try to stop the process right after the process is started using the PID and get the following error:

```
10424
Stop-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 10424.
At F:{{Redacted path}}\Dev_WAS_V85_All_Open.ps1:8 char:13
+ Stop-Process <<<< $app.Id
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (10424:Int32) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

Added code below.

```
$pid_id_array = @()
$pid_id_array_index = 0
Set-Location F:\{{Redacted path}}\scripts\windows\BlueZone
Start-Process _clip.bat
$app = Start-Process {{Redacted part of the file name}}_server1.bat -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
write-host $app.Id
Stop-Process $app.Id
$app = Start-Process {{Redacted part of the file name}}_server1_FTP.bat -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
write-host $app.Id
Stop-Process $app.Id
$app = Start-Process {{Redacted part of the file name}}_server1_DMgr_FTP.bat -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
write-host $app.Id
Stop-Process $app.Id
$app = Start-Process {{Redacted part of the file name}}_server1_ISC.url -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
write-host $app.Id
Stop-Process $app.Id
$app = Start-Process {{Redacted part of the file name}}_CLI_strings.docx -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
write-host $app.Id
Stop-Process $app.Id
$app = Start-Process {{Redacted part of the file name}}_DMgr_CLI_strings.docx -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
write-host $app.Id
Stop-Process $app.Id
exit
```

Comment: Have you opened up Task Manager and checked the PID listed there against the one Powershell gives? I tried the above code and using `Stop-Process` worked for me.

Comment: Yes, and they don't match.

Comment: Is it possible that you are starting another application that is itself starting a child process? If that is the case you will need to give us more information to assist.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Your `notepad` example works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  The notepad example does work.  The ps1 script starting at "$pid_id_array = @()" to the end of the code block does not work.

Comment: Why do you need an array of process IDs?

Comment: Each Start-Process is a view into a single server using a different tool.  I work on over a dozen different servers.  I have a Open-All powershell script and and Close-All powershell script for each of the dozen servers.  My desk top is too cluttered to keep 6x12= 72 windows open.  The array of pid allows me to invoke the Close-All powershell script which issues a Stop-Process on all the pid in the array for a given server.  This keeps the number of windows open on my desk top to a minimum.

Comment: wait-process waits for the process to be stopped.  stop-process would never see the process.